# passing different date as parameter in calling a user defined function with a loop in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, date, parameters

let say I have a user defined function which take date
as parameter i.e. to_date ,from_date but it has a limitation that it can provide data of maximum limit
of three months but I need data of one year
how I am suppose to do that..
function

```
select *
from table(height_DOL.DOL_PKG_DATA.FN_GET_height_DATA(IN_FROM_EFFECTIVE_DATE => '11-JAN-20',IN_TO_EFFECTIVE_DATE => '11-APR-20'));
```

with the help of loop in oracle

Comment: It is always good to provide some sample data along with expected output for a better understanding and quick response!

Comment: The function, which you must use, returns only dates with in the past three months, and you want to overwrite/bypass that so it returns dates up to a year instead of three months?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` if you can not change the function:

```
select *
  from table(height_DOL.DOL_PKG_DATA.FN_GET_height_DATA(IN_FROM_EFFECTIVE_DATE => '11-JAN-20',IN_TO_EFFECTIVE_DATE => '11-APR-20'))
UNION ALL
select *
from table(height_DOL.DOL_PKG_DATA.FN_GET_height_DATA(IN_FROM_EFFECTIVE_DATE => '11-APR-20',IN_TO_EFFECTIVE_DATE => '11-JUN-20'))
UNION ALL
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach what can be used to filter down 1 year data-

```
SELECT *
From T
WHERE date_column > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

**Or This**

```
select *
from
height_DOL.DOL_PKG_DATA.FN_GET_height_DATA
where IN_FROM_EFFECTIVE_DATE => '11-JAN-20' and IN_TO_EFFECTIVE_DATE <= '11-APR-20';
```

Comment: this is not a table it's function on which we have to pass date as parameter ...